# Using smb share on windows

Tags: windows-10, android, file-transfer, smb

I enabled th SMB1 feature in my windows 10. How to use it to transfer files between my android and windows-10
I have a filemanager+ android app which asks to enter url, usernames password for smb connection
Where do I generate this url username and password?

Comment: What I do in my Linux systems in the file manager is:  smb ://ipofwindows10/folderordrive/  and authenticate.  The Windows 10 system as authorized the folderordrive to be accessed with specific credentials.

Comment: How do I check if SMB is enabled to pass through the firewall?

Comment: SMB is a connection method like NET USE.  I have not had it blocked by regular firewall settings. Try pinging the Windows device from the Android device.